# How to get text from selected row in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a data grid view that displays data from a SQL table.

I need to get the text from a specific column in the selected row on a mouseclick to use it in a new SQL query.

How do I do that in vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this:

(Datagridview1.Item("Coloumname", e.RowIndex).Value.ToString)